# How to modify a const reference in C++

Tags: c++, constants

I am new to C++ and I am trying to modify some existing code. I basically have to modify a const reference variable in C++. Is there a way to do so?

I want to remove a subtring from a constant string reference. This obviously wouldn't work, since id is a constant reference. What would be the correct way to modify id? Thanks.

```
const std::string& id = some_reader->Key();
int start_index = id.find("something");
id.erase(start_index, 3);
```

Comment: `const_cast<std::string&>(id).erase(start_index,3)`. I'll let other people tell you why this is a bad idea.

Comment: Remove the `const` modifier.

Comment: The API you are programming against obviously doesn't want you to modify the return value; are you sure you need to do this?

Comment: @BenjaminBannier Yes, that's true, it is a bit of a hack. But this is the quickest way I could do this, and it's for a research project, so I guess it's good enough for now..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a copy of the string and modify that, then set it back (if that's what you need).

```
std::string newid = some_reader->Key();
int start_index = newid.find("something");
newid.erase(start_index, 3);

some_reader->SetKey(newid); // if required and possible
```

Other routes shall be avoided unless you know what you're doing, why you're doing it and have considered all other options ... in which case you would never need to ask this  question in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If it is const and if you try to change it, you are invoking undefined behaviour.

The following code (using char * instead of std::string& - I could not exhibit the error with std::string) in order to use a const_cast compiles and breaks at run-time with *Access violation when writing at address ...* :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const char * getStr() {
    return "abc";
}
int main() {
    char  *str = const_cast<char *>(getStr());
    str[0] = 'A';

    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So stick to @Macke's solution and use a non const **copy**.